# Пауза в Parallel.ForEach. Как правильно объявить паузу и продолжить ?c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Использую Parallel.ForEach в качестве многопоточности, возникла проблема в добавлении паузы и продолжения работы.

```
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@dann[0]);
                int kol = Convert.ToInt32(dann[1]);
var pr = File.ReadAllLines(@dann[2]);
        var opt = new ParallelOptions
                {

                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = kol
                };
                Parallel.ForEach(lines, opt, a => start(a, pr));
```

как тут правильно поставить паузу, а затем продолжить ?

Comment: Где именно Вам нужна пауза и зачем ?

Comment: мне нужно приостановить многопоточность, тобишь в процедуру старт я посылаю строку и массив. Допустим прошла большая часть массива lines, (например всего 10 строк ) я ставлю паузу (через некую булеву переменную) и в процедуру старт уже не передаются значения (остановилась на 6 стоке), после продолжения работы (изменил обратно булеву переменную. например) опять начался вызов процедуры с ранее остановленного места (с 6 строки)

Comment: простите, я плохо выражаю свою мысль, надеюсь, что вы поняли, если нет, то постараюсь перефразировать

Comment: Нет, все отлично. Вам нужно заюзать лямбду. Посмотрите [вот этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535368/pausing-and-resuming-a-parallel-foreach) пример.

Comment: Если не справитесь, разместите где-нибудь в облаке Ваш код, я помогу.

Comment: было бы не плохо, но нужно самому вдуплить, что там происходит. иначе никогда не пойму. 
п.с вы имеете в виду код процедуры старт ?

Comment: Да, как мне кажется, использование внутри лямбда-выражения условий в этом примере - хороший пример для Вас (метод StartProcess()). Дайте ссылку на код Вашего приложения, завтра на работе напишу.

Comment: https://note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/6687449d478d3d9be09c17f7685fc0ed?page=1
спасибо за помощь

Comment: можно пока вопрос ? в примере есть state, которая и позволяет делать паузу  state.Break(); , а что у меня это ?

Comment: Как я понимаю, нужно оперировать Thread.CurrentThread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий подход.

Добавьте в ваш код поле

```
ManualResetEventSlim mres = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
```

В методе `start` добавьте вызов

```
mres.Wait();
```

В том месте, где нужно включать/выключать паузу (например, в обработчике нажатия кнопки) напишите

```
if (mres.IsSet)
    mres.Reset();
else
    mres.Set();
```

Использование класса `ManualResetEventSlim` гарантирует потокобезопасность.

Comment: спасибо большое, вроде работает

Comment: а как тут вообще остановить многопоточность ?

Comment: @Lolidze - одна тема - один вопрос. Тем более не задавайте вопросы в комментариях, задайте новый отдельный вопрос. А так, смотрите [отмену задач](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) с помощью `CancellationToken` и [остановку цикла](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460721(v=vs.110).aspx) с помощью `ParallelLoopState`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, смотрите, если заюзать такой код - должно сработать. Однако, тут один поток, и весь смысл использования `Parallel.ForEach` теряется (MaxDegreeOfParallelism  = 1). В противном случае, блокировка будет срабатывать для нового потока, который создает `Parallel.ForEach` и для того потока, в котором он работает, а это уже не совсем то, что нужно.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace parallelOutput
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void MainTask(ManualResetEvent re)
        {
            string[] recs = 
            { 
                "str_01", 
                "str_02", 
                "pause", 
                "str_03" 
            };

            ParallelLoopResult plr = Parallel.ForEach(recs,
                new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = recs.Count() }, (string rec, ParallelLoopState pls) =>
                {
                    if (rec != "pause")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} ", DateTime.Now, rec);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        re.WaitOne();
                    }
                });
        }

        public static void StartTask(ManualResetEvent re)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            re.Set();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManualResetEvent re = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            Thread st = new Thread(() => StartTask(re));
            st.Start();

            Thread mt = new Thread(() => MainTask(re));
            mt.Start();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @Lolidze, да не за что, тем более, по-сути Вашей проблемы я не решил. Как я понял, конкретно для кострукции _Parallel.ForEach_ такой прием применять нельзя. Хотя, если кто-то докажет обратное - буду только рад )

Comment: а пример выше ? он вроде как работает нормально

Comment: @Lolidze, сейчас спросим у VladD )

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой, наверное, метод останавливать/запускать код такой:

Объявляем общедоступный объект:

```
object mutex = new object();
```

В том месте, которое должно быть остановлено (например, на каждой итерации цикла):

```
lock (mutex) { /* ничего не делать, сразу освободить */ }
```

В том месте, где надо запретить выполнение:

```
lock (mutex)
{
    // тут выполнение потоков остановлено
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}   // а тут снова разрешено
```

Ну или если нужно в одном месте запретить выполнение, а в другом разрешить, то

```
Monitor.Enter(mutex); // запретить
// ...
Monitor.Exit(mutex);  // разрешить
```

---

Но если вам нужно запускать/останавливать выполнение кода, `Parallel.ForEach` наверное не лучшая идея: ведь в нём внутренний планировщик предполагает, что ему нужно выполнить всё как можно быстрее, и не знает о том, что ваш код будет останавливаться.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйуста, а можно ли будет использовать Ваш метод в том случае, когда нам требуется _некое_ событие, для того, чтобы остановить/возобновить работу ? Надеюсь, не сочтете мой вопрос попыткой доказать преимущество моего метода на Вашим - как-то обостренно стали участники относится к комментариям к их ответам ))

Comment: @isnullxbh: Ну по идее можно. Например, останавливать через `Monitor.Enter`, а по приходу события сделать `Monitor.Exit`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо !

Comment: @isnullxbh: Пожалуйста!

Comment: спасибо, за помощь, принцип я уловил, что вы можете сказать насчет метода Alexander Petrov'а ? по идее, у него принцип примерно такой же

Comment: @Lolidze: У него тоже хороший метод.

Comment: Последнее замечание верное. В моём примере, если не ограничивать принудительно `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, то после паузы планировщик запускает дополнительные потоки (гораздо больше, чем ядер), так как засекает, что дело не движется. Вернее, он запускает их во время паузы, но все потоки стоят на `mres.Wait()`.